# Why can't I read in missing datetime values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, spss

I want to read in a date type variable from SPSS into an Python Dataframe, If the date is missing then I get an error message and I'm not sure how to fix it? Just how a missing numeric value is coded as NaN, I'd like something similar for missing date variables.

```
# Read in SPSS Database
with sRW.SavReaderNp('C:/Users/Sam/Downloads/File.sav') as reader:
record = reader.all()
SPSS_df = pd.DataFrame(record)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Sam/Python/Program.py", line 17, in 
>       SPSS_df = pd.DataFrame(record)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sam\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 436, in **init**
>       mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sam\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 257, in init_dict
>       return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sam\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 82, in arrays_to_mgr
>       arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sam\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 323, in _homogenize
>       val, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False, raise_cast_failure=False
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sam\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 664, in sanitize_array
>       subarr = _try_cast(data, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sam\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 784, in _try_cast
>       subarr = maybe_cast_to_datetime(arr, dtype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sam\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py",
>   line 1100, in maybe_cast_to_datetime
>       value = tslibs.conversion.ensure_datetime64ns(value)
>
> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 123, in
>   pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.ensure_datetime64ns
>
> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.pyx", line 118, in
>   pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
>   pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds
>   nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00

print (Record) shows the following, the actual dataset is larger but the last line is in essence where the issue in fact occurs.

```
(b'86600   ', '2019-08-05T00:00:00.000000')
(b'86600   ', '2019-08-05T00:00:00.000000')
(b'86600   ', '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000000')
```

Comment: Can you show us what `record` looks like?

Comment: Edited. I'm assuming I could edit this date or something? Just to say I usually decode every column in the dataframe, but I can't even print the dataframe because of this error

Comment: Have you checked the sRW  documentation ? https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/index.html#dateformats

Comment: I have, I'm guessing rawMode=True fits in somewhere I'm just not sure where?